# SysGCC toolchain can't find files in sysroot

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors, raspberry-pi

I set up [this](http://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/) toolchain on my Windows machine for my Pi (raspberry-gcc4.6.3-nosysroot.exe) and then I followed the instructions [here](http://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/tutorial/sysroot) to synchronize my sysroot.

I use a library called WiringPi in my project, and I have confirmed that it is in the synchronized sysroot:

[image: wiringPi]

Then I attempt to compile it:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Wall -O -c main.c
```

But I get the following error:

```
fatal error: wiringPi.h: No such file or directory
```

What do I have to do to make the compiler find the header file? I thought the whole point of synchronizing the sysroot was to make this kind of thing work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to let gcc know where to look for the include files via the [`-I`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) argument. In the case above, `-IC:\SysGCC\Raspberry\...\usr\local`. You may have to add more than one include path, depending on where the required files are scattered. You can also try to set gcc's [environment variable(s)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables).

Finding out the correct include path can be a little tedious (see above: should it be `local\` or `local\include\`?). Maybe you can find the environment setting for all default include paths on your Pi and just copy it over to your Windows machine.

Edit: Think I got it: [`echo | gcc -v -E -`](http://sysprogs.com/w/building-a-win32-gcc-cross-compiler-for-debian-systems/)

Comment: How can I set those paths on Windows? Can I just do it in Windows' environment variables configuration?

Comment: Either pass them as command line arguments (`-I`) to gcc, or set up the environment variables, or declare them in your `makefile` or IDE project.

Comment: Yes, the usual Windows env. variables should do the trick. (After changing one, all (parent-)processes which use them should be exited and re-started; this includes open Windows and MinGW consoles.)